# javascript not work in library or list

Tags: sharepoint-server

i have to update user column in JavaScript. I appended the code in master page and set a time out about 3 second. Now, the function doesn't executed unless user f5 the page (click next page -> function not work -> f5 -> work).

```
setTimeout(function(){
             var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                var tmp =elements[i];
                if(tmp.innerHTML.indexOf("my checking string") > -1){
                    tmp.setAttribute("href", "/_layouts/15/xxxx.aspx");
                }
            }
            },3000);
```

**update for window.onload**
[image]

Comment: i guess the page wont reload when click next/prev page

Comment: need to see code

Answer (score 4):

need to see code but im going to assume that you need to wrap your functions to wait for the dom to load. On the first instance the code is executed before its ready. Second time code is in memory hence why it works.

```
$(function(){

  //all code goes here or the first function that calls others 

});
```

or the longer way:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  //all code goes here or the first function that calls others 

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

**EDIT**

if you cant use Jquery use javascript

```
<script>
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames('setTimeout');
setTimeout(function(){
             var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                var tmp =elements[i];
                if(tmp.innerHTML.indexOf("my checking string") > -1){
                    tmp.setAttribute("href", "/_layouts/15/xxxx.aspx");
                }
            }
            },3000);
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, jquery or 3rd party is not allowed. first i tried to call window.onload, but sharepoint system function will override the event.

Comment: then i called the onload event of body, it also been override.

Comment: just updated my answer. use the javascript version instead of jquery

Comment: window.onload is fail because sharepoint system will override your function if you insert the script in master page

Comment: upload the screen cap FYI

Comment: just updated my answer